# XSLT transformation is not working when used in php

Tags: php, xml, xslt

So, far I have a tested XSLT transformation that does working (test.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:export="http://startrek.csd.auth.gr/dr-device/export/export.rdf#" xmlns:defeasible="http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/systems/dr-device/defeasible.rdfs#" xmlns:carlo="http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/systems/dr-device/carlo/carlo-flex.rdf#">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
            <br/>
                <h1>Matchmaking Results</h1>
                <br/>
                <h2>Compatible apartments to your requirements</h2>
                 <br/>
                <table border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th><p class="p1">Apt Name</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Centrally located</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Price</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Size</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">No of bedrooms</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Floor</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Size of the garden</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Has a lift?</p></th>
                            <th><p class="p1">Allows pets?</p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//export:acceptable"/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                 <br/>
                <h2>Most suitable apartment for you</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//export:rent"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="export:acceptable">
        <xsl:if test="defeasible:truthStatus='defeasibly_proven_positive'">
            <xsl:variable name="apt" select="export:apartment"/>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$apt"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:central"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Centrally located -->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:price"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Price-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:size"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Size-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:bedrooms"/>
                </td>
                <!-- No of bedrooms-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:floor"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Floor-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:gardenSize"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Size of the garden-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:lift"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Has a lift?-->
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('carlo-flex_ex.rdf')//carlo:apartment[carlo:name=$apt]/carlo:pets"/>
                </td>
                <!-- Allows pets?-->
            </tr>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="export:rent">
        <xsl:value-of select="export:apartment"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The problem appears when I use it in php.** By using it there, I have just the text printed in my website (Apt Name, Centrally, etc), no data at all.

```
// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load($response); //export.rdf 

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('test.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I can't understand why it is not working when XSLT transformation is called by php.
Is seems like  xsl:apply-templates is not working at all. Am I missing something? Should I add something else in php or xslt code? Any possible help would be really appreciated! thank you.

PS i use PHP Version 5.5.6 with XSL enabled (libxslt Version 1.1.2)

Comment: Is it possible to be an issue regarding XPath used in the xslt file and php??

Comment: I don't see an transformation call in your PHP. (*btw* Why do you register all PHP functions for your XSLT template. You're not using any.)

Comment: You are right, I missed it when copying the info here (I was just testing). Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It may be that your XSLT processor doesn't support the `document()` function, or that it can't locate the file `carlo-flex_ex.rdf`. Are you sure you've put that file in a place where your XSLT processor can access it?

Comment: document() is supported by PHP (libxslt). If here is an error in the XSLT, PHP should output it. Is the error reporting fully enabled? You can capture/output the errors manually using the [libxml functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Perhaps, the problem is in the XSLT file. It has to merge data from two rdf files since the first file indicates an "apartment id" ("<xsl:if test="defeasible:truthStatus='defeasibly_proven_positive'">") and the other contains the rest data for the apartment but still I'm not sure if there is something wrong with this xslt althoug it is valid.